# How to use the w3 validator API

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, w3c-validation

I currently have an online code editor and would like users to be able to validate their HTML code using the w3 validator on my site. When the user clicks check-code, this function is called:

```
$.get("//validator.w3.org/check", function(data) {
     alert(data);
});
```

But nothing happens. How do I incorporate the W3 validator in the AJAX request?

The documentation for the validator is here: http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html

Comment: How would it validate the markup unless you somehow pass it to the API ?

Comment: Thats my question :) How do I pass in that data?

Comment: Read the docs, you pass it as either uri, uploaded_file or fragment, so something like `http//validator.w3.org/check?fragment=escaped_html_goes_here`

Comment: @adeneo It seems like that doesn't work. Nothing happens at all.